# Deep Linking react native expo

Tags: react-native, expo, deep-linking

I'm trying to make a deeplink so that my user enters the application through the link of a certain product, the idea is to take him to a specific screen. but I am not tolerant:

I'll post parts of my code:

```xml
<manifest
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.deliveriesapp"
>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
  </queries>
  <application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
  >
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="AIzaSyBsM5n_Yxz4ccj9zaedzzHFI3EkeiLABvI"
    />
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
      android:value="AIzaSyBsM5n_Yxz4ccj9zaedzzHFI3EkeiLABvI"
    />
    <meta-data
      android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED"
      android:value="true"
    />
    <meta-data
      android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION"
      android:value="48.0.0"
    />
    <meta-data
      android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH"
      android:value="ALWAYS"
    />
    <meta-data
      android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS"
      android:value="0"
    />
    <meta-data
      android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL"
      android:value="https://exp.host/@vanessashirlenee/deliveries_app"
    />
    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen"
      android:exported="true"
    >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="exp" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
      android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"
      android:exported="false"
    />
    <uses-library
      android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
      android:required="false"
    />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

`npx uri-scheme open "exp://192.168.1.6:19000/-/myapp/ProductDetail/64d2b15149cde9aba42d8286" --androidveries_app>`

I'm just not able to make it available to my client through the browser

I tried to configure it in a few ways, and also try to run it in a way that can take my client to the app